# Looking for a way to correctly order ctags matches

Tags: vim

I have a codebase that has `ctags` configured correctly. When I do, `:tjump keyword` it shows me a list of potential matches for the `keyword`.

However these matches aren't ordered correctly. I'm looking for a way to correctly order the matches so that the best match is at the top of the list. ie:- the first jump when I directly use `Ctrl-]` should go to the correct place.

For the GetFile navigation with `gf` I have found `includeexpr` which allows me to run custom logic to determine the file to jump to.

> Does Vim have a similar function for altering the `tags` results?

Another approach I am considering is to grab the list of tags from `:tjump`, do sorting, and override the mapping for `Ctrl-]`.

> For this approach, is there a function to get the list of matches from `:tjump`?

Any other ideas to ensure that the the correct match is at the top are also welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often not clear what the "correct" match is. Currently Vim uses the following logic (from `:help tag-priority`):

```
When there are multiple matches for a tag, this priority is used:
1. "FSC"  A full matching static tag for the current file.
2. "F C"  A full matching global tag for the current file.
3. "F  "  A full matching global tag for another file.
4. "FS "  A full matching static tag for another file.
5. " SC"  An ignore-case matching static tag for the current file.
6. "  C"  An ignore-case matching global tag for the current file.
7. "   "  An ignore-case matching global tag for another file.
8. " S "  An ignore-case matching static tag for another file.
```

If you want to implement your own custom logic, there's nothing (that I know of) similar to the `includeexpr` that can help you.

You could create multiple tags and order them in the `tags` setting in such a way that encodes your preference. It's hard to say what that would be, though, and very likely to require some experimenting.

Another, more complicated thing you could do is override the `<c-]>` key (and maybe others, like `<c-w>]`) to do something different. Something like:

```
nnoremap <c-]> :call <SID>JumpToTag()<cr>

function! s:JumpToTag()
  " try to find a word under the cursor
  let current_word = expand("<cword>")

  " check if there is one
  if current_word == ''
    echomsg "No word under the cursor"
    return
  endif

  " find all tags for the given word
  let tags = taglist('^'.current_word.'$')

  " if no tags are found, bail out
  if empty(tags)
    echomsg "No tags found for: ".current_word
    return
  endif

  " take the first tag, or implement some more complicated logic here
  let selected_tag = tags[0]

  " edit the relevant file, jump to the tag's position
  exe 'edit '.selected_tag.filename
  exe selected_tag.cmd
endfunction
```

You can use the `taglist()` function to locate the tags for the word under the cursor. Then, instead of `let selected_tag = tags[0]`, you can implement your own logic, like filtering out test files, or sorting by certain criteria.

Unfortunately, this doesn't maintain the `:tnext` and `:tprevious` commands, since you're manually editing files. You could replace it with the quickfix or the location list, using the `setqflist()` function with the tags ordered the way you like and then navigate using `:cnext` and `:cprev`. But that's a whole lot of more scripting :). If you decide to go down this rabbit hole, you might want to take a look at the source of my [tagfinder](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/tagfinder.vim) plugin for inspiration.

Comment: This is a super answer! Thank you! I'm going with `taglist`. I have only a couple of `interface` defs that are false positives that need to be filtered out. The Tagfinder plugin looks great too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to @AndrewRadev's answer:

I often create a "mktags" script that builds ctags and then filters out of the tags file the ones I want to omit.  For example (for sh, ksh, bash, zsh):

```
ctags "$@"
egrep -v "RE-for-tags-to-delete" tags > tags.$$
mv tags.$$ tags
```